# Backing up laptops with redirected folders + offline files

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup

I have users that have their common folders (mainly My Documents) redirected to our server.

Many of them also have offline files enabled so that they can have those files available when they're not on the LAN.

We are deploying end-point backup software on every laptop that will backup to the cloud.

My question is: is it common practice to setup end-point backup software on laptops to backup the redirected folders?  We are having trouble getting this to work, as the backup software runs under LOCALSYSTEM, and doesn't have access to the redirected folders of the individual user.

Should I just configure the endpoint backup software to backup files that are physically on the laptop and ignore the redirected folders?

Comment: Don't you have backups on the server these folders are redirected to?  Your backup software on the endpoint probably can get the cached offline files, but I don't understand why you would try to backup the redirected folders target.

Comment: Right - and the server is backed-up.  However, part of the requirement is that users be able to do self-recovery of their files.  If I only backup the files on the device itself, that'll exclude most of the user content.  So "self recovery" will be useless to the user.  From what I understand, Windows stores teh offline files in a cache folder in a custom format, so that I can't effectively backup the offline files.

Comment: **Do they need to self-recover offline?**  Users can access the volume shadow copy service if you have it enabled on your servers while they are connected?  This provides users with a very easy to use self-service restore.